# mysql md5 select not returning record

Tags: mysql, md5

I have a table with passwords that are hashed with MD5. When I do a select, no records are returned.

```
select *
from this-table
where username = 'username' and password = MD5('password');
```

If I drop the password, it returns 1 record. I also tried it without the `MD5()`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you show md5 hash of password? I assume its text "password" itself encrypted?

Comment: Does `SELECT MD5('password')` return the same value that's stored in the password column? Is the password column at least 32 characters long?

Comment: *Please* read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php What you're doing is very vulnerable to cybercriminals.

Comment: If I do a select MD5('password') it returns the MD5 hash. The field is  a varchar 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the capitalization? The output from the MD5() function is always lower-case. Also, the capitalization of the password before being hashed is also important; "abc" and "ABC" produce completely different MD5 hashes.

Comment: If I check the MD5 value direct from the database with a select, it doesn't match the MD5 value created in php query. I had the php script log the ND5 value. Is this normal?

Comment: Instead of generating the MD5 in PHP and then sending it to Mysql, I would suggest generating the MD5 using the Mysql function MD5(): `INSERT INTO this-table (username, password) VALUES ('name',MD5('password'));`.

Comment: Thanks bluecollarcoder. I haven't had time to test it but I think you are correct. I ran the insert without the MD5 and manually ran a MYSQL update to convert it to MD5, now everything works fine.